# Decode json with key and Any type Value

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have a JSON file and I want to use `[String: Any]`. The problem I'm having is that I get an error:

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'decode'

I would love to understand where I am wrong.

```
struct MyModel: Decodable {
    let myDictionary: [String: Any]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case myDictionary
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let data = try container.decode([String: Any].self, forKey: .myDictionary)
        self.myDictionary = data
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that `Any` is not `Decodable`. `JSONSerialization` may be an alternative. Could you provide some sample JSON data?  Perhaps there is another solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a **[String: Any]** dictionary is not compliant to the **Decodable** protocol because of the **Any** part. Which concrete type is not automatically inferred.

But don't worry, in your case this is not a problem. You have just to read your file content and use **JSONSerialization** to cast it to **[String: Any]**.

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{  
    "object": "customer",
    "id": "4yq6txdpfadhbaqnwp3",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "metadata": {
        "link_id": "linked-id",
        "buy_count": 4
    }
}
"""

struct Model {
    var dictionary: [String: Any]
    
    init() {
        dictionary = [:]
    }
    
    init(data: Data) {
        self.init()
        if let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
            self.dictionary = dictionary
        }
    }
    
    init(string: String) {
        self.init()
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            self.init(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then decide if you want to create your Model from a **String** or **Data**.